# BASH shorten filenames contain screenshot

Tags: bash

I would like to replace the "Screenshot" substring with "Ss" for all the files in the current directory (if easy, add for subfolders). Currently I have this code, but needs to be completed/replaced:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *; do
echo "${f}" | cut -c1-10
done
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```sh
for f in *; do 
  mv $f ${f/Screenshot/Ss}
done
```

if need move to sub directory

```sh
mkdir -p foo
for f in *; do 
  mv $f ./foo/${f/Screenshot/Ss}
done
```

if your filename contain space, make sure to put the variables in double quotes.

```sh
mkdir -p foo
for f in *; do
  mv "$f" "${f/origin with space/replace name}" 
done
```

Comment: It works! Thank you.
I had to remove the #!/bin/bash thing and also I had to run it with ./ instead of with sh.

Comment: This won't work if a filename contains whitespace. Also the variable name in `for` is wrong.

Comment: Edited. Now it can work if filename contains whitespace.